# MySQL - Add a fixed static row to result

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL statement that returns a list of user_id's

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_links WHERE linked_user_id='1234'
```

The `user_id` never contains the `linked_user_id` that I use in the `where` clause. So I want to always add the from clause "linked_user_id" in the result but also want to sort by the user_id ASC.

Is there a way to do this in the MySQL statement itself or do I have to do this with some other scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your condition to add that `user_id`:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_links WHERE '1234' in (user_id, linked_user_id)
```

Let's sort it accordingly:

```
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM user_links 
    WHERE '1234' in (user_id, linked_user_id)
    ORDER BY user_id
```

Or you can even guarantee that the linked user id will be the last row by:

```
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM user_links 
    WHERE '1234' in (user_id, linked_user_id)
    ORDER BY user_id = '1234', user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_links WHERE linked_user_id='1234'
UNION ALL
SELECT '1234'
```

Comment: In this case using `UNION` is unnecessary, as one can achieve the desired result by tweaking the condition. Also, the question asked for sorting by `user_id` as well.